# .htaccess proxy for bots

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, seo, prerender

I just wrote a blog with the create-react-app. In addition to that I wrote a small service which will render the site using chrome on the server for crawlers like Google or Facebook.

So I have `http://example.com/path-to-page` which should be served to regular users and there is `http://myprerenderer.com/render/http://example.com/path-to-page` which should be served to crawler etc.

This is what my .htacces currently looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

# redirect non www to www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

# One year for image files
<filesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|svg)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</filesMatch>

# One month for css and js
<filesMatch ".(css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2628000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

This works fine to every url I visit is served by the react apps index.html (I'm using react router btw.).

Now, how do I need to adjust my .htacces for this scenario:
The crawler visits the site, is redirected (or proxy?) to the prerenderer which then serves the website using chrome - but there shouldn't be another redirect if the the site is already visited by the prerendering service.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to add something similar to the Prerender.io .htaccess to detect the crawler and proxy (not redirect) the request to your prerendering server:

https://gist.github.com/thoop/8072354

Comment: Thanks! So will this rule proxy it? `RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) http://myprerender.com/render/http://staging.diffusmag.de/$2 [P,L]`

Comment: That will proxy the request as long as the requested URL is not one of those static files. There are also some RewriteCond checks in the Prerender.io gist that checks to see if the request is coming from a crawler.